# Convert XML into a single string I can fit into an xls cell

Tags: xml, csv, groovy, soapui, xls

I am currently trying to use Groovy to write a long xml response into a csv that when opened in excel will place the XML resp in a single cell.

Currently when it writes it and I open the CSV in XLS the XML is across many cells and columns.

The original structure when read is in a single cell, but I can not come up with a way to put the response after it's been processed back into a single cell.

So far I have tried simply `File.Append(structureResp)` File representing where mCSVsv file is being created and StructureResp holding my response back from my SOAP UI project.

I have also attempted to use some regex to solve this and remove spacing. but that does not seem like a good option.

Comment: use any csv library to write. it could be http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#writing_from_an_array_of_strings or http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: It's not enough to convert xml into single string because it could contain `,` and `"` and you have to escape all those symbols.. And with library you don't need to reformat xml into a single string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using string builder to place XML in single csv/xls column not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280694/using-string-builder-to-place-xml-in-single-csv-xls-column-not-working)