# Using string builder to place XML in single csv/xls column not working

Tags: java, xml, csv, groovy, soapui

I am having an issue with an XML response and formatting it into CSV which can then later be opened as an XLS and see the entire response into a single cell. I know.. its not how I would do it either, but they get what they ask for.

So far I have tried to use a string builder. This has been successful in formatting the response into a single line string, I have tested this by writing it to a text file and copying it to Eclipse.. when I place single quotes around the XML it turns to a string.

When trying to take this same response in its single line format and stick it into a csv file.. the csv file is breaking on comma's in the XML string and placing the response across several dozen cells.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File('responseXml.txt')));
    String l;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    while((l=br.readLine())!= null){sb.append(l.trim());
    File respfile = new File("outresp.txt")
    respfile.append(l)
    println respfile.text
//verified single line string  
    respContents = new File("outresp.txt").text  
                    }

    File file = new File('outXML.csv')
    file.append(respContents)
    println file.text   

// open csv still broke across many lines
```

What I would like is a single xml string into a single xls cell.

Answer (score 0):

to fit value into single column in csv (excel) you have two choices:

1. remove all new lines (`\r\n`) and comas (`,`)
2. replace each doublequote (`"`) with two ones (`""`) and wrap whole value with doublequotes.

the second variant allows you to keep the original (multiline) string format in one excel cell.

here is the code for second variant:

```groovy
//assume you have whole xml in responseXml variable
def responseXml = '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
<aaa text="hey, you">
    <hello name="world"/>
</aaa>
'''

//take xml string in double quotes and escape all doublequotes
responseXml = '"'+ responseXml.replaceAll(/"/,'""') + '"' 

def csv = new File('/11/1.csv')
csv.setText("col1,col2,xml\nfoo,bar") // emulate some existing file
csv.append(",${responseXml}\n")
```

as a result:

[image]